# Istio is using external IP

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

Node has two network interfaces, internal and external. Kubernetes is set to use an internal network interface for node communication:

```yaml
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: InitConfiguration
bootstrapTokens:
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: "10.x.x.x"
```

After I closed all (except needed) ports on the external interface of the worker node I am getting this on `ingressgateway`:

```
stream logs failed Get "https://149.xx.xx.xx:10250/containerLogs/istio-system/istio-ingressgateway-85784bd4b6-lwv56/istio-proxy?follow=true&tailLines=100&timestamps=true": dial tcp 149.xx.xx.xx:10250: i/o timeout for istio-system/istio-ingressgateway-85784bd4b6-lwv56 (istio-proxy)
```

How to make Istio use internal network IPs for that?

Self-managed Kubernetes 1.23.3,
Istio 1.12.3 (using Istio Operator)

---

#### Additional info

This could be relevant to this issue. There is NodePort service that exposes Istio `Gateway` ports:

```yaml
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  name: config
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  profile: default
  components:
    base:
      enabled: true
      
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          service:
            type: NodePort
            externalTrafficPolicy: Local
            selector:
              app: istio-ingressgateway          
            ports:
              - name: http
                port: 8000
                targetPort: 8000
                nodePort: 80
              - name: https
                port: 1443
                targetPort: 1443
                nodePort: 443
```

`ingressgateway` prints only error provided in my question.
Using default DNS configuration. Using Calico to close external network interface ports (not using iptables directly):

```yaml
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: FelixConfiguration
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  FailsafeInboundHostPorts: []
  FailsafeOutboundHostPorts: []

---

apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: HostEndpoint
metadata:
  name: wn-bond1
  labels:
    role: worker-ext
spec:
  interfaceName: bond1
  node: wn

---

apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: inbound-external
spec:
  selector: role == 'worker-ext'
  preDNAT: true
  applyOnForward: true
  order: 0
  ingress:
    - action: Allow
      protocol: TCP
      destination:
        ports: [80, 443]
---

apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-outbound-external
spec:
  selector: role == 'worker-ext'
  applyOnForward: true
  order: 0
  egress:
    - action: Allow
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. How exactly did you set up your whole infrastructure? Please attach ingressgateway logs to the question. How is look like your DNS and iptables configuration?

Comment: Added more information to my question. Please let me know if anything else would be useful.

Comment: Please run `kubectl logs` on another pod and see if you get the same error as before. Please also look [at this site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#non-public-ip-used-for-containers). It is described similar error. Then please let me know ;)